# SwiftFolder is Empty Error while posting iOS App to Appstore ITMS-90424

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, app-store

I have recently completed building my first iOS Application and I am ready to post it. While posting it Apple sent me a email saying that my SwiftFolder is Empty (ITMS-90424). I checked my Swift Folder and it is empty though I do not know how to fix this error. I have went through other forums including some Stack Overflow ones though none of them seem to fix the problem. Please let me know if you have an answer to this problem.

Information to Note:

Mac OS: Catalina
Cocoapods: Yes
Firebase: Yes
Swift Version: 5
Xcode Version: 11.4.1

Thanks,
Tech Star 123

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved the problem by manually deleting SwiftSupport from archive before submission. After you archive, open the archive file and find SwiftSupport folder inside in it, then find SwiftSupport folder and delete it. Then you are ready to submit the archive. Go back to Organizer and submit it. It will work.